# Best Dev Environment for Drupal (in Windows 7), researched options inside

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, environment, drupal-8

Are there pre-built environments for Drupal development that includes all the right tools like drush, apache, phpmyadmin, etc.?

Only option I am able to find it [Drupal QuickStart](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickstart) bit it does not look maintained at all as the last commit was 2 years ago.

I want to have my setup as a Virtual Machine so that I am never crippled by one machine going down and having to set everything up again.

I am primarily first looking at environments for Drupal 7 but also would like it to work with Drupal 8, for when I make the move.

My Research shows the following options so far, would love to get any more options

[Drupal QuickStart](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickstart)

[VM for Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/project/vm) Looks like for drupal 8 only and not sure how this works.

[Vagrant Drupal Development](https://www.drupal.org/project/vdd) - This looks like the most promising. Anyone have experience with this?

PS: I hope this question is not deemed too broad. I have tried to do the research and provide options to keep the discussion very focussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for a simple dev environment, get Acquia Dev Desktop 2 from Acquia (Dries created the company). It's free and basically creates what you need in a "standalone" application. Find it here: https://www.acquia.com/downloads.

I've used the Mac version, and it works fairly well.

Creating a VM via Vargrant and Chef is a great way to go (basically VDD, the third option you put out above), but it requires a bit more of an understanding of server administration with some sort of Linux distribution, so the learning curve is a bit steeper. If you're looking to replicate your production server environment on your Desktop, then you can basically clone the server and have it run locally, but, again, most people don't need an exact duplicate for basic development.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal Pro seems promising (I have not used it)
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalpro

But also VDD is not for drupal 8 only
there is some releases for drupal 7 but they are hidden from the project page
https://www.drupal.org/node/2008018/release

Answer (score 0):

You may try with www.drupalvm.com . This includes very smooth vagrant based development environment setup.

Comment: does the vagrant environment include your own toosl like a custom VIM setup?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Drupal Pro for the past 5 years. It's basically a Virtual machine with Ubuntu installed catered for quick Drupal development. Some benefits:

- Quickly create Drupal 7 / 8 sites in less than 20 seconds
- Everything is contained in the Virtual machine
- Easily move assets around from one site to the other.
- Linux environment that closely resembled the prod server environement
- Work from the terminal using VIM

I just updated the Drupal Pro to Ubuntu 14.04 (2016-May) using the following: https://www.drupal.org/node/2559371

Pics:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I want to add my choice of [Wamp64](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download-wampserver-64bits/) (Linux, Apache, always the latest PHP 7.x, MySQL 5.7, etc..) as a suggestion for **multi-sites (Virtual sites in various folders with separate MySQL databases)**, and it doesn't use any kind of VMs/Docker. Already tested (daily) and it works!

And it works perfectly on Windows 7 as well :) Just needs all kinds of VC++ libraries, nothing more.